# How can I transition NM cable (coming out of drywall to peninsula cabinet) into conduit with THHN wiring for the peninsula outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, kitchens, conduit, junction-box

I have a roll of NM at the end of one of the (currently inactive) 2 kitchen circuits, which the electrician left for peninsula wiring. NM is coming out of drywall, under the counter, going directly into the peninsula cabinet.

(I'd rather we skip ALL the NEC 2023 ambiguities about having that outlet at all, and focus just on the right hardware needed for the best transition out of the wall into the cabinet for wiring.)

So... 90 degree conduit body, going "into" drywall? Or into a metal faceplate on a recessed box, with a knockout faceplate (especially if I'd rather use the box to transition from NM to THHN)? Just the conduit going directly into the knockout faceplate? Or even, simply the conduit... "diving" into drywall? Or extension box over regular recessed box, exceeding the wall, so that conduit can go simply into a side knockout on the extension box, parallel to the wall?

I'm not liking any of those, even if it is all covered inside the cabinet... Appreciate all your suggestions, especially those that provide specific hardware, couplings etc.

Thank you!

Comment: How about using a recessed box to transition to armored cable?

Comment: With a knockout faceplate, armored cable fitted into the knockout faceplate, just like it would be into any knockout? In terms "working," I guess it would work, but there's something really off about a flex cable coming 90 degrees off of wall... idk? :) Doesn't feel very "inspector friendly" 

Comment: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Sigma-Electric-ProConnex-3-8-in-Squeeze-Connector-Flexible-Metal-Conduit-Compatible-Conduit-Fitting/1090809

Comment: This makes sense indeed. And you think, "code-wise," this would be best-ish, optimum solution?

Comment: I guess I could do the same thing with liquid tight conduit as well... Although the only 90 degree liquid tight coupling that I know is a wide round one, so probably would look way jankier?

Comment: The AC is adequate for code. Without more information it's hard to comment on how one or the other looks. I'm so used to seeing armored cable in spots like yours that it would look ordinary. The liquid tight would look odd because the environment down there doesn't warrant it. Some inspectors would probably even let you staple the NM in the back upper corners.

Comment: Are the peninsula cabinets one-side-only, already set as back-to-back, or to be determined?

Comment: Cabinets are side to side attached to each other, forming the peninsula, which is attached to the wall - 60 inches from the wall to the edge. The NM is coming directly out of the wall (from roughly 15 inch under the countertop) into the cabinet carcass, loose in a 10 ft roll.

Comment: I feel like the ideal scenario would be if I could attach an LB conduit body into a faceplate. Behind the faceplate NM would be transitioned in a... junction box? Running a rigid conduit from LB to the outlet would be the "sleekest" and safest then. Or not? :)

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something. The "sleek" is an unusual criterion for stuff buried in the back of a bottom cabinet. Is this work going to be visible for people who aren't on their hands and knees? Why the intense interest in the aesthetics of something totally hidden from sight?

Comment: Haha, no it's more about the inspectors here, who really double down on how homeowner electrical work "looks." Like, really "craftsman-like" and "professional looking." But also, I'm really curious how there's no standardized solution to probably something that happens a lot, thanks to NEC 2020: transitioning romex in wall (not ground), to protected wiring in peninsulas. There has to be a "this is how you do it" way, but I feel it is left to interpretation?

Comment: @JCott -- I take it there's a single row of cabinets then, not two rows?

Comment: Is there any requirement for conduit at all? Clearly bare NM is accepted in your jurisdiction. It surely could be secured inside the cabinetry in such a way that it would not be subject to damage (as by moving drawers for instance). In instances where physical protection is required conduit may be used to provide that. But in those cases the conduit is not used as a "wiring method" and the usual requirements for LB's and pull boxes and stuff aren't applicable.

Comment: Is this wiring for electric outlets in the back or end side of the cabinets, or something?  If so, what's wrong with simply using a Jbox at the drywall end of the cabinet, and running the NM inside smurf tube (along the inside face of the cabinet backs) to the outlets?  (I'm imagining the side of one cabinet butted up against the drywall.)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yep, one row, and outlet at the end, under the counter.

Comment: @GregHill :) Neither my city, nor do I approve of exposed NM wiring. Having kids, my experience is what's unlikely for a professional becomes a life target for those imaginative little monsters. I fished hiding kids from kitchen cabinets many times! And city-wise, they don't like seeing cabinets as regular NM location which requires some extra protection. And I agree. It should be conduit with THHN wiring. But this all is not the question. How to transition specifically out of the drywall.